# DateTimePicker wpf toolkit binding

Tags: wpf, binding, wpftoolkit, datetimepicker

How to bind the Selected DateTime in WPF Toolkit's or extended Toolkit's DateTimePicker as I do not find a SelectedDateTime property?

I guesses I might need to bind it with the '**Value**' property but I am not sure. No documentation is available.

I am using MVVM.

Comment: This question really helped me - I'd been binding to the Text property and was getting some strange date format conversion problems!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For `DatePicker` it's `SelectedDate` property, and for `DateTimePicker` it's `Value` since there's no other property with type `DateTime`.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate}" />

<xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding MyDate}"></xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

And if you are using .Net 4, there's already a build-in DatePicker, so no need for the Toolkit, there isn't a DateTimePicker though.

Comment: I had been using WPF DatePicker only, but my requirement is DateTimePicker. I tried binding with Value property and it binds successfully. I figured it out though. But thanks for reassurance. :)

Comment: I wish the full DateTimePicker would be integrated. I'm using the xceed extension only for this.